# could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.diagnostics.strace, version

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

I have a domain controller on which I have SQL Server installed. All databases are setup to automatically backup everyday. Recently the error found in the footer started popping up whenever I login to an instance of the SQL Server Management Studio, and hence it disabled the automated backups. I searched the internet for a solution and the majority of the solutions were to "**format**" the pc! which I can't due to many complications.

I read somewhere on microsoft support blog that the solution was to "[Uninstall SP1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1600dea6-a434-4cfb-87ce-472018cf64fd/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoftsqlserverdiagnosticsstrace-version10000)"

What SP1? can anyone help?

The error

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dmf.PolicyStore' threw an exception. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of formatting your PC, just fire up the installer package for your version of SQL Server (in my case, I accidentally uninstalled VS 2010 Shell, which it SQL Server Management Studio needs).

From the SQL Server Installation Center:

1. Maintenance Section
2. Repair

That should fix any problems you're having.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I uninstalled SQL Server Management Studio. Reinstalling fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the Shared Management Objects MSI file (32 or 64-bit based on your system architecture) It'll surely fix this issue.

Comment: Could you explain what that is and why it'll solve the problem, so as to make your answer more useful?